# Multiple Tailwind config files for one NextJS Project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

My question is, is it possible to have two configurations(tailwind.css) for two NextJS layouts?

Basically I want a frontend-tailwind.js and a backend-tailwind.js to generate two styles sheets **backend.scss** and **frontend.scss** in **two Next layouts**...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you work with `laravel` in backend ?

Comment: Nope the same NextJS project manage front en back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created two layouts and add on each  I added a classic link stylesheet (example below)

```
<link rel="preload" href={process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? `/css/tailwind-dev.css` : `/css/prod.min.css?${refreshCache}`} media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And I use two Gulp tasks, one for building TailwindCSS dev (with all themes) and one for building the prod files (with purgecss, cleanCSS, concat...)...
PurgeCSS regex is here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production